# How to represent multiple parameters using simple UI

Tags: website-design, gui-design, dashboard

I have 6 categories out of which 5 categories have 3 parameters and 1 category has 1 parameters.

I am showing those categories against unique ids, as mentioned below.

Suppose there is one unique id `TII-123`, it will show on UI like this:

```
category        parameters         value         unique id 
C1              P1                 X1            TII-123
C1              P2                 X2            TII-123
C1              P3                 X3            TII-123
C2              P1                 X1            TII-123
C2              P2                 X2            TII-123
C3              P3                 X3            TII-123
C4              P1                 X1            TII-123
C5              P1                 X1            TII-123
C5              P2                 X2            TII-123
```

Whihc seems a little complicated on UI for the user to use the information, how can i represent the same information in better way on UI group by unique id.

Note: The Unique ids can be more than one, in that case the exiting UI looks like mess.

Comment: Could you please explain what `unique id` is? How could it be more than one? If yes, why is it called unique id?

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful? https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131135/display-hierarchical-dataset-in-a-digestible-format

Answer (score 1):

I am unclear about how and why the unique id fields have the same values.
But regardless, the following way of representation solves your case.[image]

> We can use chips for the values in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing here is how the output of a database query might look if it's been denormalised.

One approach could be to normalise the data in the UI using grouping as you suggest, by switching the column order to display least likely to change on the left and most on the right.

There may be further optimisations but what you likely want to do is remove duplication. So if something is unique show it once, show each category once, then only show the things which vary in the category.

[image]